# using a specific emacs server

Tags: emacs

I usually have 3 or 4 emacs open because I am working at 3 or 4 different projects in different workspaces. Now when I try to open a new file using emacsclient  I don't have a control on which emacs it goes to. Usually it goes to the emacs in other workspace. Is there a way to specify which emacs to open it into ?

One way is to restart the server in which I want that file to go but its not the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the server socket file a specific name and then invoke emacsclient to use that socket:

```
(defun get-tmpdir ()
    (or (getenv "TMPDIR") "/tmp"))

(defun start-named-server (name)
    (let ((server-name (format "%s/emacs-%s" (get-tmpdir) name))
        (server-start))
```

Now define a shell script 'ec' that will allow you to specify the server name:

```
emacsclient -s ${TMPDIR-/tmp}/emacs-${1?"usage: ec [emacs server name] ..."} "$@"
```

So now you can go "ec 1 myfile" after you have run M-: (start-named-server "1") in your emacs, and repeat for all your other emacs' with 2, 3, 4 ...

Answer (score 5):

Burton's solution is on the right track, but is overly complicated because you shouldn't need to futz around with the name of the temp dir.  You can just do:

```
(defun start-named-server (name)
  (let ((server-name name))
    (server-start)))
```

and then use

```
emacsclient -s <name> "$@"
```